# How do I save forecasted values to use in calculations in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, forecasting

I have a report that uses a couple years of historical data and uses the Tableau forecasting to show expected values for the next three months. I would like to be able to save these values for a few reasons.

1. I need to do calculations on the forecasted values. Multiple different people will be using this forecast and will need different calculations. Some will need to calculate 70% of the forecasted value, and some will need to calculate different percentages. I'd like to have a parameter for them to enter the percent and be able to create a calculation using the parameter and the forecasted value.
2. I would like to be able to save forecasted values to later show the difference between what was forecasted and what actually happened. I understand you can export your data from your forecast and import that as another data source to show actuals vs forecast, but I need to do it all automatically with no manual intervention.

Is this possible? I haven't found any way to save the values or do calculations on the values that are forecasted. I am using Tableau 10.5

Answer (score 1):

Tableau will never save data.  Probably easiest to create the forecast values in the datasource and then report.  It's very simple to have "actual" values and "forecast" values so you can compare

Comment: I prefer to use Tableau’s forecast because I have different forecasted values based on filters due to regions. Some of the forecasts for certain regions have trend and seasonality while others do not. There is not one forecast that best fits all of the different regions. So it wouldn’t be as easy to come up with my own values

Comment: So the only other way I can suggest is to right-click on the view, select View Data and then click the Export All button.  That will give you a new column (Forecast indicator) which includes Actual (the data you provided) and Estime (the data Tableau calculated).  You will have to remove the Actual data manually.